# Implement Google Analytics With Userid in Open Cart

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, opencart

i want to track every customer how could i do it the documentation on google analytics have this code

```
ga(‘set’, ‘&uid’, {{USER_ID}}); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
```

how do i pass userid in this as open cart have an admin panel setup to enter google analytics and ehat if my customer is not logged in what should i do.

Comment: Hope `$this->customer->getuserid()` will give you the user id. You can add this to ga the code

Comment: @Lepanto It's actually `$this->customer->getId()`.

Comment: I sense the usual misunderstanding here - the Userid feature will not help you to tell users apart. It's there to enable cross-device-tracking, but you will still get aggregated data.

Comment: @Eike then what should i do to get the userid in tracking so that i can track every customer by their id on google analytics

Comment: You have to use a custom dimension in the user scope in addition to the user id (you can use the same value, the dimension is needed to expose the value in the interface). Bear in mind that you must not use anything that reveals the users identitiy (an id that you tie to your backend system is okay, though) and no unqiue device identifiers (IMEI and the like). Custom dimensions  do not show up in standard reports, you need to create custom reports.

Comment: @eike can you give me the code because the code on their support side is confusing me a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opencart uses a setting in administration where you insert your whole GA code. You can use it as well for user tracking. The only change you'd do is to add this line of JS code into that field in administration:

```
ga('set', '&uid', #CUSTOMER_ID#);
```

This string will be then parsed by PHP in `catalog/controller/common/header.php` like this - find this line

```
$this->data['google_analytics'] = html_entity_decode( ... );
```

and after this line put this code:

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
    // replace %s with customer ID
    $this->data['google_analytics'] = str_replace('#CUSTOMER_ID#', $this->customer->getId(), $this->data['google_analytics']);
} else {
    // customer is not logged in, remove the user tracking part
    $this->data['google_analytics'] = str_replace("ga('set', '&uid', #CUSTOMER_ID#);", "", $this->data['google_analytics']);
}
```

This should do it - also with the check if customer is logged in.

Comment: Thanks man it is working, but on my google analytics it is still showing aggregate data, what i want to do is i want to track every customer by their id so that i can track which user id visited which url and blah blah. Can you tell me the process.

Comment: I'm not a GA specialist but a quick Google search drove me to [this resource](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables). Hopefully it solves your problem. If you'd be using the new **analytics.js**, you could do it [this way](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id).